# Encrypt hard disks with VeraCrypt in a mixed Windows / Linux system

Tags: windows-7, linux, hard-drive, boot, encryption

My system is a dual boot Ubuntu / Windows PC. I installed several hard disks: Two SSDs (one for Windows 7 Pro, one for Kubuntu 15.04) and some conventional disks for data.

Currently the Linux disk has highest boot priority in BIOS. Grub provides a boot menu there that allows booting into Windows when selected. Both system currently don't use UEFI.

I want to encrypt all of the disks (systems and data). And I want to allow the encrypted data disks to be accessible from both sides, Windows and Linux.

I am thinking about using VeraCrypt for this job. However most guides in the web are talking about systems with Windows and Linux partitions located on the same hard disk, not on separate hard disks.

Is there a way to install VeraCrypt on both operating systems, to encrypt both system disks (and the data disks) and to use pre-boot authentication for both operating systems without breaking anything (especially the ability to select the desired OS to be booted on startup)? How exactly?

Comment: Since your question is, more or less, two-fold and potentially complicated, you may want to contact Idrix, the developer of Veracrypt, directly. There is a contact form for inquiry at the following link: [ https://www.idrix.fr/Root/mos/Contact_Us/Itemid,3/ ] Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, However since I got no answer here I moved on and used other encryption strategy for linux. The remaining problem is now a bit more specific: http://superuser.com/questions/974060/using-grub-to-boot-into-encrypted-windows-disk. If you have no idea about that one, I will try the form.