# Using GRUB to boot into encrypted windows disk

Tags: windows-7, linux, boot, grub, truecrypt

This is similar to other questions already asked here before. Still none of them actually answered my problem.

My PC has two SSDs. One containing Windows 7, one containing Kubuntu 15.04.

The Linux disk is configured as boot disk in BIOS. Its MBR contains GRUB. The Windows disk has the standard bootloader in its MBR. When booting, GRUB provides a menu that allows me to boot into Linux or into Windows.

Currently Linux is encrypted (LVM+LUKS). Windows is not. I would like to encrypt the Windows disk using TrueCrypt/VeraCrypt.

I tried to encrypt the Windows disk as if there were no other disk and no other OS installed on the computer (selecting "single-boot" in the encryption wizard).

I expected this should work... GRUB and Linux remain unchanged but when booting
into Windows, no password request from VeraCrypt appeared and the PC booted directly into Windows and I got a dialog telling me that the password/boot test failed.

How can this be solved? Why don't I see the VC password request?

Comment: Did you ever get this to work correctly? I'm thinking about implementing something similar. Did you try to update the grub menu on the Linux side after encryption?

Comment: No, I was not able to get that working. Without the necessary knowledge I decided to not encrypt Windows. Finally I moved Windows to a VM hosted in Linux. That solved all the problems and turned out to be the better solution for me since it has a lot of advantages.